# Imported a library to an old project and got error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I imported a ui-library to an old project in android studio. Everything goes fine until I add `compile project(':Android Library'` to build.gradle of my app module. Here is the setting in build.gradle of app and library respectively.

App

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.chimaera.AppName"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile project(':MaterialDesign')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Library module

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

(I forgot to paste the error.) Here is the error tips.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPg9L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTRSB.png)

It jumped to a value.xml seems unrelated to this error.
I set `minifyEnabled` to false for release but keep debug setting blank. Do I need to set debug as well. Is there anything wrong with version settings to cause imported error?

Comment: WHat is the error??

Comment: Post the error or we can't do anything at all.